# Wordpress Flyout Menus

Tags: menus

I have a bit of a complicated menu structure that I am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

**I have a top nav** that has 4 SECTIONS. Each Section has upto 2 levels deep.

Also, **I have a SUB Nav** that is based on what section you are in and displays as a drill down showing what page you are own.

For example, say I click on a second level TOP NAV - I would then go to that SUBPAGE showing the SUB nav having that section open and selected.

I hope I explained that correctly...

Thanks.

My Question is: What is the best way to do this. I've researched some plugins but I can't seem to find the right one. I don't have to use a plugin.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic. Your question is probably too specific to your site for you to get much action here.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a plugin. Just trying to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: I was thinking for the right menu to use a series of conditinal widgets with the portion of the menu that relates to that section. Not sure how I would do the expandable. Not sure there is an easy way aside from doing a custom jquery menu...

Comment: I also got UberMenu from code canyon that works perfect for the top menu, so I supposed I can just use the conditional widgets on the right. I dunno yet.

Comment: Ok I got what I needed. I used uberMenu and an accordian menu combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also got UberMenu from code canyon that works perfect for the top menu, I can just use the conditional widgets on the right.